# R data.table : filter and create new column at the same time

Tags: r, filter, data.table

Is there possibility to create new column and filter data at the same time in data.table? e.g:

data frame:

`test <- data.table(mtcars)`

when I use below command:

`test[mpg > 18, test_col := 1]`

I get new column with values=1 only for row which meet filter assumptions, but I'd like to get something like this:

`test <- test[mpg >18]
 test[, test_col := 1]`

Can I do this in one line in data.table? I hope you understood my problem.

Comment: If you need to subset `test[mpg>18][, test_col :=1]`

Comment: `test[mpg > 18][test_col := 1]`. Please go through [the vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)..

Comment: there should be one extra leading comma in Arun's code before `test_col`

Comment: Your anserws are incorrect. I want to summarize data frame - not create new colum. Solution is to use setNames():

`DT_mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)


x <- "yyy"

DT_mtcars[, setNames(.(sum(hp)), x), by = cyl] `

Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347363/how-do-i-pass-names-for-new-summary-columns-to-data-table-in-a-function