# How do I pass names for new summary columns to data.table in a function?

Tags: r, data.table

Say I want to create a function that calculates a summary dataset from a data.table in R, and I want to be able to pass the name of the new calculated variable in programmatically.

For example:

```
library(data.table)

# generate some fake data
set.seed(919)
dt <- data.table(x = rnorm(50), by.var = rep(c("a", "b"), 25))
dt[, list(group.means = mean(x)), by = "by.var"]  # This is what I want

# But I want to do in a function, so I can do it repeatedly:
groupMeans <- function(out.var, by.var, dat = dt) {
  return(dat[, list(out.var = mean(x)), by = by.var])  # doesn't work
}

groupMeans("group.means", "by.var")  # out.var should be "group.means"
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I would use `dat[, setNames(list(mean(x)), out.var), by = by.var]`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks. That's what I tried first.  It gives me the error: `Error in setnames(list(mean(x)), out.var) : x is not a data.table or data.frame`.

Comment: No, I'm using `setNames` from base R, not `setnames` from data.table

Comment: Aha!  That works!  Looks like I was being careless and using `setnames` by mistake.  Thanks!

Comment: Go ahead and answer it yourself - you already tried the almost correct approach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Courtesy of [docendo discimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3521006/docendo-discimus), you can use a named list created with `setNames`, like this:

```
groupMeans <- function(out.var, by.var, dat = dt) {
  return(dat[, setNames(list(mean(x)), out.var), by = by.var])  
}

groupMeans("group.means", "by.var")
#    by.var group.means
# 1:      a  -0.1159832
# 2:      b   0.2910531
```

Comment: alternatively, `structure(.(mean(x)), .Names = out.var)`... but this is more readable

Answer (score 2):

You could consider changing the column names inside your function:

```
groupMeans <- function(out.var, by.var, dat = dt) {
  res <- dat[, list(mean(x)), by=by.var]
  setnames(res, "V1", out.var)
  res
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `setnames` to name the summarised column with the 'out.var' vector.

```
groupMeans <- function(out.var, by.var, dat = dt) {
  setnames(dat[, list(mean(x)), by = by.var], 
                 length(by.var)+1L, out.var)
}

groupMeans("group.var","by.var", dt)[]
#    by.var  group.var
#1:      a -0.1159832
#2:      b  0.2910531
```

EDIT: Based on @Frank's suggestion.